# What does "绝地" mean?

Tags: translation, meaning, meaning-in-context

I am reading a novel and I have encountered this word "绝地", I thought the author made a mistake at first and meant "觉得" but I have been seeing "绝地" pop up more and more often, this leads me to believe that it is not a mistake. I tried searching up on baidu what "绝地" means, and it means "Jedi" from Star Wars but it can also mean "desperate, dangerous, dilemma". But when I try to use either definition of the word, it just doesn't make sense to me.

Here is a sentence from the novel I'm reading:
猪哥卧龙娴熟而精炼的，将绝地反击的战术策略一一解释了出来。

Could anybody informe me what "绝地" is referring to in this context/in general.

Answer (score 4):

绝 itself can mean the end of something, 地 can mean a situation. "绝地" (jué dì) can mean a desperate situation, or a situation where there is no hope of escape, survival. Here are 2 examples:

1.这个公司有大量的负债，正在绝地之中。

This company is in debt and is in a desperate situation.

2.大部分的人喜欢能在绝地成功的英雄。

Most people like hero who can survive and succeed in desperate situations.

Hope this can help.

Answer (score 2):

绝 can use to express despair, loss/giving up hope (绝望), in the same vein, 绝地 means "a dangerous place" or "a place with no-way-out".

绝地反击的战术 - a waring strategy that put oneself in a no-way-out/no-return situation, then fight back (the enemy).

Answer (score 2):

means too bad, "绝地反击" is an idiom.

Answer (score 1):

It's also a translation of Jedi, i.e. 绝地武士 == Jedi Knights.

Answer (score 1):

The origin of 绝地 comes from 孙子兵法, which means the place where the army would fail definitively.

Answer (score 0):

in a hopeless and helpless situation.

Comment: I do not understand why this is downvoted.

Answer (score -1):

猪哥卧龙娴熟而精炼的，将绝地反击的战术策略一一解释了出来。in here “绝地” = no way to escape
“绝地反击” = because no way to escape so need fights back with all his strength

Answer (score -1):

A state on the verge of collapse.It's desperate, but if anyone can summon the courage to overcome difficulties, we all think that kind of person is a worthy warrior.